# Where has 'django.core.context_processors.request' gone in Django 1.10?

Tags: django, django-templates

I used to use `django.core.context_processors.request` to get the `request` for a view in template without having to pass them in.

However, this is no longer in Django 1.10.

How to I access the request context processor in Django 1.10?

Answer (score 50):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors):

> **django.core.context_processors**
>
> Built-in template context processors have been moved to django.template.context_processors.

Comment: Note to readers: this used to be the accepted answer, until OP ragequit and attempted to punish bystanders for their [political disagreement with Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342994) in the process. Feel free to throw it an upvote to compensate if you like ;-)